# how to play video from wistia, youtube, drive in react native?

Tags: react-native

i'm new in react native. i wanna play video from Wistia, Youtube, Google Drive in my react native App. there is library for playing a variety of URLs in react native?. thanks

Comment: have you solved it? Youtube video will be played using https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-youtube

Comment: @KedarDave yes, for youtube i'm using react-native-youtube, but in other i'm using webView

Answer (score -1):

Use this library. It will allows playing video from url and several other features

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-video

Comment: can not play if the url from Wistia or Youtube.